# Android Facebook sdk 4.0 : Null exception while getting facebook user information?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the title implied, I got a null pointer exception while getting facebook user information (e.g name, user id, etc).

I notice that it happens due to these scenarios:

- No Facebook app installed
- User logs in from the facebook Intent (since there is no FB app).
- First time authenticating the app will cause a **null pointer.**

This is my code snippet for onSucces on login:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    ProfileTracker profileTracker; 

    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    final SocialProfileModel userprofile = new SocialProfileModel();

    if(profile == null){
        Log.d("user profile", "null");
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                userprofile.setProfileID(currentProfile.getId());
                userprofile.setFirst_name(currentProfile.getFirstName());
                userprofile.setLast_name(currentProfile.getLastName());
                userprofile.setMiddle_name(currentProfile.getMiddleName());
                userprofile.setProfile_pic(currentProfile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
            }
        };
    }else {

        userprofile.setProfileID(profile.getId());
        userprofile.setUserName(profile.getName());
        userprofile.setFirst_name(profile.getFirstName());
        userprofile.setLast_name(profile.getLastName());
        userprofile.setMiddle_name(profile.getMiddleName());
        userprofile.setProfile_pic(profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
    }

    tv1.setText(profile.getId()); 
    tv2.setText(profile.getName()); 



}
```

I'm aware of things like profile and token tracker, but I could not make sense of how I could make use those in this regards!

Any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Edit:

included is the stacktrace for the event:

> 04-26 16:20:10.671 2580-2580/*packagename*/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                            Process: *packagename*, PID: 2580
>                                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {*packagename*.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
>                                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                                at com.agmostudio.socialsdk.socialsdk.MainActivity$1$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:98)
>                                                                                                                at com.agmostudio.socialsdk.socialsdk_lib.login.facebook.FacebookLogin.onSuccess(FacebookLogin.java:97)
>                                                                                                                at com.agmostudio.socialsdk.socialsdk_lib.login.facebook.FacebookLogin.onSuccess(FacebookLogin.java:26)
>                                                                                                                at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:577)
>                                                                                                                at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:216)
>                                                                                                                at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:159)
>                                                                                                                at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
>                                                                                                                at com.agmostudio.socialsdk.socialsdk_lib.login.facebook.FacebookLogin.onActivityResult(FacebookLogin.java:65)
>                                                                                                                at com.agmostudio.socialsdk.socialsdk_lib.login.SocialLoginManager.getOnActivityResult(SocialLoginManager.java:103)
>                                                                                                                at com.agmostudio.socialsdk.socialsdk.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:556)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
>                                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: why not using graph api to get thses information?

Comment: whats the difference between using graph api and using Profile?

Comment: Oh. and ive tried using graphrequest.newrequestme. did not work!

Comment: need stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this two lines to your onCurrentProfileChanged method

```
this.stopTracking();
Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
```

And this in the next line after profileTracker = new ProfileTracker()

```
profileTracker.startTracking();
```

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    ProfileTracker profileTracker; 

    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    final SocialProfileModel userprofile = new SocialProfileModel();

    if(profile == null){
        Log.d("user profile", "null");
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {

                this.stopTracking();
                Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);

                userprofile.setProfileID(currentProfile.getId());
                userprofile.setFirst_name(currentProfile.getFirstName());
                userprofile.setLast_name(currentProfile.getLastName());
                userprofile.setMiddle_name(currentProfile.getMiddleName());
                userprofile.setProfile_pic(currentProfile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
            }
        };
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }else {

        userprofile.setProfileID(profile.getId());
        userprofile.setUserName(profile.getName());
        userprofile.setFirst_name(profile.getFirstName());
        userprofile.setLast_name(profile.getLastName());
        userprofile.setMiddle_name(profile.getMiddleName());
        userprofile.setProfile_pic(profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
    }

    tv1.setText(profile.getId()); 
    tv2.setText(profile.getName()); 



}
```